# Elliptic Curves over finite field of characteristic p

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

A **Weierstrass equation** of the form $y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6$ over some field is called *elliptic curve* if the discriminant $\triangle \neq 0$. If the characteristic of the field is not equal to 2 and 3, then the above elliptic curve is transformed to the **normal form** $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ and the discriminant $\triangle =4a^3+27b^2 \neq 0$.

My question is that, can we write an elliptic curve in normal form over some finite field with characteristic 2 or 3 and having nonzero discriminant.

For instance, $E:y^2=x^3+x+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$. Here the discriminant $\triangle =4a^3+27b^2 = 1 (\text{mod } 3) \neq 0$.

Is it correct or wrong? Am I making any mistake somewhere?

Comment: Yes you can write some but NOT ALL. For example, I think that $$y^2+xy=x^3+x+1$$ cannot be written in normal form over $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: @N.S. Yes, for this case discriminat=0.

Comment: In characteristic two, the equation $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ NEVER describes an elliptic curve. Because the derivative $Dy^2=2y=0$ everywhere, the curve is singular, and hence genus zero.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In characteristic 2, due to $y^2=c$ always having a double root, it is clear that $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ is not good. What about $y^2+y=x^3+ax+b$, do we really need a $xy$ term  ?

Comment: @reuns No, we don't. Over $K=\Bbb{F}_{2^m}$ we can put any elliptic curve in to one of the forms $y^2+y=f(x)$ or $y^2+xy=f(x)$ with a cubic monic $f(x)$. The former are wildly ramified above $x=\infty$ and have no points of order two due to the automorphism $y\mapsto y+1$ (the function field is an Artin-Schreier extension of $K(x)$). Curves of the latter form have the automorphism $y\mapsto y+x$, and a single point of order two with $x=0$. Using simple linear substitutions we can always get rid of either the $y$-term or the $xy$-term,

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Tks. The automorphism is that of the inverse in the group law. Thus, the reduced form of the equation is telling directly about supersingular-ness, ie. about $End(E)$ being a quaternion algebra or a subring of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$.

Comment: @reuns BTW. I don't know if you are at all interested in the goals of [the Pearl Dive](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31105/11619). But you are one of the users whose opinion I generally trust. So if you see a post with a little bit extra oomph, out-of-the-box thinking, a nice argument not straight outta textbooks), or something like that please give your endorsement to that post in [the dedicated chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102837/pearl-dive).

Comment: @reuns No pressure, of course. If you don't want to have anything to do with that project, that's fine :-)